# Nodejs on VPS only running on my network

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, centos, vps

Nodejs server which is installed on my VPS is accessible only on my network. People from outside world cannot access it. If its online, it should either be accessible all over the world or nowhere. What to do?

Code in my js file:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

// Also tried http.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0", function(){
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening to port 3000');
});
```

Comment: I think it's a network configuration problem, not a specific node one.

Comment: almost 10 people said the same that they can't load the page, I experience the same if I turn off Wifi and switch to mobile data on my phone. The page takes forever to load

Comment: Everything is fine with this config. Do you have anything at port 80? Try with this one, cause for any reason maybe port 3000 is somehow blocked at your vps? Or maybe you've got something wrong with your vps setup. Cause this command have to work. (I'm assuming that you've provided some routes, cause if not then nothing got to be returned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad adding the site's IP as the second parameter of listen function solved it.

```
http.listen(3000, "xx.xxx.xx.xxx", function(){
    console.log('Server listening to port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your question you say that you want the Node app to be accessible to everyone in the world, or nobody at all. If you're VPS provider restricts you to only running things on an internal network, however, then it is impossible to do what you are asking.

The network rules will simply not allow it.

With that said, however, I'm going to make a recommendation for changing your Express application. Here's how it should look:

```
let express = require('express');

let app = express();

app.listen(3000);
```

The code above will bind your Node application to port 3000 in the simplest way possible using Express directly. This is probably what you want.

Also: please note that if you are intending to build a public service, you will need to likely do one of two things:

- Bind your Express server to port 80 (for HTTP), or
- Use a web server to proxy requests from port 80 (HTTP) to port 3000 (local).

Comment: I don't need the above http variable at all?

Comment: I also need to run socket.io which requires http

Comment: The stuff I am showing you is just how to run an express app simply. If you need to use socketio / other stuff, you can add whatever else you need.